# What is the difference between managed tomcat and embedded tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6, jboss-arquillian

I am not sure that I understand the difference between these two types of tomcats (embedded and managed).

I am going to setup arquillian test for my project on tomcat and I have to choose between embedded tomcat or managed tomcat (since there are different ppom.xml settings and dependencies). Please tell me what is the difference and which one I should choose for running my arquillian tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer from the "Arquillian testing guide" book.

Embedded containers: Arquillian will start up for you during the test process and shutdown after the test are run, on the same JVM as your test case.

Managed containers : Arquillian will start up for you during the test process and shutdown after the test are run but run in a different JVM

Remote containers : assumed to be running prior to the test and will simply have deployments sent and tests executed